# ReactJS - toggling a class from one component, force the other component to rerender

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm trying to figure out how to get a component to re-render after I have changed a state value that the class list is dependent on.  I'm assuming because it is not a direct property of the component, it is not re-rendering for me.

My Details component that I want to re-render when the `showDetails` state variable changes:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ScheduleContext } from '../../schedule-context';

const Details = () => {
    const showDetails = useContext(ScheduleContext).showDetails;
    const className =
        'col details-col' + (showDetails ? '' : ' d-none');

    return <div className={className}>details...</div>;
};

export default Details;
```

That state variable is set in a different component that is essentially an aunt/uncle from the Details component:

Order Component partial code:

```
const toggleDetails = () => {
        setShowDetails((showDetails) => !showDetails);
    };

    return (
        <Draggable draggableId={orderID} index={props.index}>
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
                <MyOrder
                    className={'order'}
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                    isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
                    onClick={toggleDetails}
```

From my reading forcing a re-render of a component is frowned upon.  So I'm assuming there is a way to have this cleanly automatically re-render when I update that state variable.

Comment: So basically, you want to create an element with details that you can show or hide from anywhere in your application?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so

Comment: Try to impose the state from all affected classes from a parent component by passing its state properties as props. When the state in the parent changes, all dependent child components will get updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `Details` parent

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ScheduleContext } from '../../schedule-context';

const SmartComponent = () => {
    const showDetails = useContext(ScheduleContext).showDetails;

    return <Details showDetails />;
};

export default Details;


// Dumb component
const Details = ({ showDetails }) => {
    const className = 'col details-col' + (showDetails ? '' : ' d-none');

    return <div className={className}>details...</div>;
};
```

It's a good pratice to have smart components that handle dumb components